# what does the following equation represent?

Tags: summation, p-adic-number-theory

I have the equation:

$f(x)=1+\sum_{i={1}}^{\infty} a_{i} X^{I} \in 1 +X\Omega[[X]]$

in my book.I think it is meant to represent powerseries or polynomials. I cann't make sense of what is what thou. can somebody explain?

Comment: $\Omega[[X]]$ denotes formal power series over a ring $\Omega$.  Somewhere in your text, a ring $\Omega$ was introduced.  Note $X\Omega[[X]]$ are the power series without constant term.

Comment: @fredgoodman what does it mean that the second term is an emergent of 1? or what is written dosent mean that?)

Comment: "Emergent of 1" is not meaningful to me.

Comment: “Emergent”: are you quoting from an English-language text, or are you translating into the English word “emergent”?